# Migration sipjs to jssip

Tags: webrtc, jssip, sipjs

I changed lib sipjs to jssip. I have problem on session transfer.
in sipjs this look like this

```js
session_from.refer(session_to);
```

How i can do this on jssip?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell it works *very* similarly. Instead of referring to the `SIP.Session` JsSIP has a `JsSIP.RTCSession` with `refer`:

http://jssip.net/documentation/2.0.x/api/session/

```
rtcsession.refer(target, options)
```

where the options are optional, so you end up with the same exact call.